# Add Hyperlink onClick of hyperlink in extJs

Tags: extjs

In extJs how to add hyperlink onclick of some other hyperlink. 
This main hyperlink is value of a cell in a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the grids cellclick event to intercept the link click and execute another operation.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    //[...]
    listeners: {
        'cellclick': function (iView, iCellEl, iColIdx, iStore, iRowEl, iRowIdx, iEvent) {
            iEvent.preventDefault();
            var zRec = iView.getRecord(iRowEl);
            if (iColIdx === 1) {
                alert(zRec.get('name'));
            }

        }
    }
    //[...]
});
```

> It is important to call the preventDefault() method on the event object to abort the link click event.

Here is the complete example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21cg